# Cannot change text value of input element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning `React` so sorry if the question is silly. Anyway, I'm trying to change the text of an `Input` element if the `filtered` variable is `null`, so I did:

```
const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext);
const text = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

const { filterContacts, clearFilter, filtered } = contactContext;

useEffect(() => {
    if (filtered === null) {
        text.current?.value = '';
    }
});
```

but on this line: `text.current?.value = '';`

I get:

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.

what I did wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
return (
        <form>
            <input
                ref={text}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Filter Contacts..."
                onChange={onChange} />
        </form>
    )
```

Comment: Are you using controlled input or uncontrolled?

Comment: @AgustinMoles I have update the question showing the input return

Comment: The error is literally telling you to change `text.current?.value = '';` to `if(text.current){ text.current.value = ''; }`. Whether or not it's necessary to use a ref is different matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message is pretty clear about what's wrong in your code.

**Optional-chaining is not valid on the left-hand side of the assignment statement** and you get this error because of the following statement in the `useEffect` hook

```
text.current?.value = '';
```

You can only use optional-chaining on the right-hand side of an assignment.

You can replace your optional-chaining code to an `if` statement

```
if (text.current) {
   text.current.value = '';
}
```